# Is there a combinator for this?

Tags: scala, recursion, combinators

I have a list of strings

```
val allLines = List("James Bond", "secret agent", "", "Martin Odersky")
```

I then want "map" that to e.g. a `List[Person]` where `case class Person(name: String, moreDetails: List[String]` using *several elements at once*.

```
val people = allLines.someCombinatorFunction { lines => 
   val name = lines.head
   val (moreDetails, remainingLines) = lines.span(_ != "")
   val person = Person(name, moreDetails)

   (person, remainingLines)
}
```

this should give me:

```
List(Person("James Bond", List("secret agent")), Person("Martin Odersky", Nil))
```

Ie. I want to take a variable number lines, combine them to a Person, and "hand off" the remaining lines. `List[String] => List[Person]`. This is trivial with recursion:

```
def linesToPeople(lines: List[String]): List[Person] = { lines => 
   val name = lines.head
   val (moreDetails, remainingLines) = lines.span(_ != "")
   val person = Person(name, moreDetails)

   person :: linesToPeople(remainingLines)
}
```

... but!, recursion is expensive, unless you make it tail-recursive..:

```
def linesToPeople(lines: List[String], acc: List[Person] = Nil): List[Person] = { lines => 
   val name = lines.head
   val (moreDetails, remainingLines) = lines.span(_ != "")
   val person = Person(name, moreDetails)

   linesToPeople(remainingLines, person :: acc)
}
```

^ This is where it becomes a little too cumbersome imo. You also need to do a `.reverse` in the end to get the order right. A combinator would be nice here

So basicly, I have a list, I want to *"consume"* & combine a variable number of its elements, and return the remains. Is there a way to do this without resorting to recursion?

Comment: The delimiter between strings that should be used for one person is an empty string `""` in the list (or the end of the list)? I don't think there's a pre-made function for this.

Comment: If you try to think about it... almost every consumer is - `look -> examine -> Consume -> start again with rest` kind of recursion.

Comment: Yes! This is so common that there's *got to be* a combinator for it?

Comment: Also, recursion is perfectly fine, especially if you are programming in a functional style. Why do you want to avoid recursion?

Comment: Recursion is very costy unless you use tail-recursion; which forces you to take an accumulator as a parameter. Then it becomes a little cumbersome imo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalaz has a function `selectSplit` for that:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def getPeople(lines: List[String]): List[Person] = 
  lines.selectSplit(_ != "").map(l => Person(l.head, l.tail))
```

And then:

```
scala> getPeople(List(
  "James Bond", "secret agent", "", 
  "Martin Odersky", "", 
  "Arnold Schwarzenegger", "Terminator", "governor"))
res8: List[Person] = List(Person(James Bond,List(secret agent)), Person(Martin Odersky,List()), Person(Arnold Schwarzenegger,List(Terminator, governor)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a fold—it's possibly not quite as specifically applicable as you'd like, and it's a little noisy, but it works:

```
val (last, rest) =
  allLines.foldLeft((None: Option[Person], List.empty[Person])) {
    case ((None, people), line) => (Some(Person(line, Nil)), people)
    case ((Some(last), people), "") => (None, people :+ last)
    case ((Some(Person(name, details)), people), line) =>
      (Some(Person(name, details :+ line)), people)
  }

val people = rest ++ last
```

The basic idea is that you're carrying along an accumulator that also indicates the state of the processing. In this case I'm using a list of completed people and an `Option[Person]` that contains the person currently having details added (if any).

I'd typically suggest using combinators like fold and avoiding explicit recursion, but in this case I think it's less of a slam dunk—the (explicitly) recursive version is a lot clearer.